# Set other parameters during view animation in android

Tags: android, animation

I am animating scale of a text view `v` using `ObjectAnimator`. While this animation is in progress, I want to also update the position of the view. I don't know ahead of time what the new position would be. When I call `v.setX` during the animation, the position is not changing. So what am I doing wrong? Do I need to call `setX` from the same thread that launched the animation? Or in the update listener of the animation?

I start the scale animation, and as and when I get the position updates I would like to update the position:

```
ObjectAnimator anime = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view, scalex, scaley);
anime.start();
```

and in a separate function I am doing this:

```
view.setX(x)
```

Comment: try `v.setTranslationX`

Comment: @pskink, I tried and it did not work. By the way, I am passing absolute coordinates in terms of pixels to `setX`.

Comment: did not work? what does `did not work` mean?

Comment: [this](http://pastebin.com/bZgE7Mq0) animation scales and translates the button, check it out

Comment: When I tried `v.setTranslationX`, the position did not change. However if I remove the scale animation, then the position is changing as expected. I am unable to open your link as of now (office firewall). Thanks!

Comment: @pskink, setTranslationX (being called separately from the animation) is working only when I removed the scale animation.

Comment: The code you shared does translation in the animation update callback, and i think it sure works. However my question is: can i do the same translation from outside the animation callback -- because i don't know what the end position would be when starting the animation.

Comment: The position updates come through other thread at random intervals during the animation.